# How to show pymongo.errors.OperationFailure details?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am getting a pymongo OperationsFailure in python when writing to MongoDB. Is there a way to print out the detail or code attribute in addition to the traceback?

Also see: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.OperationFailure.details

So far I am using:

```
try:
  connection.test.foo.find_one()
except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure:
  print "caught"
```

Comment: Thanks for downvote without a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Works:

```
try:
    connection.test.foo.find_one()
except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure as e:
    print e.code
    print e.details
```