# When I use pymongo2.8, There is a error(pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: None)

Tags: python, pymongo

When I run code like this:

```
#!/bin/env python
#encoding:utf-8
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages')
print sys.path
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.guping
```

the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_mongo.py", line 8, in <module>
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line     374, in __init__
    self._ensure_connected(True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 939, in _ensure_connected
    self.__ensure_member()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 813, in __ensure_member
    member, nodes = self.__find_node()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 873, in __find_node
member, nodes = self.__try_node(candidate)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 720, in __try_node
    {'ismaster': 1})
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 703, in __simple_command
helpers._check_command_response(response, None, msg)
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 133, in _check_command_response
  response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: None
```

The env:

- python 2.7
- pymongo 2.8

When I run the code on windows8, it's worked well 
but run on VPS(centos),there is always something wrong

---

I use pymongo 3.0.2 , there is a error like this: [pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No servers found yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663931/upgrade-to-pymongo-3-0-resulting-in-serverselectiontimeouterror)

I can't solve it, so change to pymongo 2.8

But there still err...

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Is the mongod instance running and try the following step d=MongoClient(host="localhost",port=27017) . Is there any password or so

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai Change "host="localhost",port=27017",  still error, and no password

Comment: is the mongod instance running are you able to connect from cmd prompt

Comment: @VigneshKalai yes, I can connect mongodb with command line.

Comment: It is working correctly for me don't know whats the issue sorry

Comment: but I think you could look in to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407471/how-to-show-pymongo-errors-operationfailure-details

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai When I use try...except..., There's no more useful information. thank you anyway, :-)